# Saving the state of buttons in dynamic Table View Cells in one UITableViewController to view in another

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Here's the scenario. I have a UITableViewController with dynamic cells. Each cell has 3 buttons that the user can click. At another point in the app I need the User to see another UITableViewController that is NOT editable and has the same states for the buttons as the User saw after he was done clicking around in the first UITableViewController.

In other words, it's a history page. Right now the first UITableViewController has a UITableViewControllerDataSource, and I've tried just using that same datasource for the second Table View Controller, but for some reason it won't work. When the user navigates backwards on the app to see the first UITableViewController they originally made the selections on, it saves the states just fine, but when they make it to the end of the app, the new UITableViewController has all new (unselected) states for those buttons.

I also need the second UITableViewController to have different colors and a few other small differences as the first, but for now I'm most concerned about making sure I can access those states from earlier.

Here is my datasource:

```
class DepressedButtonTableViewControllerDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, DepressedSelectionTableViewCellDelegate {

//MARK: Array for putting in my selections, and some other important variabls for managing choices
var choices: Array<Int> = []
var result = 0
var advanceArray: Array<Int> = []

// MARK: - Table view data source

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 3
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "depressedSelection", for: indexPath) as! DepressedSelectionTableViewCell

    let firstThing = "placeholder"
    let secondThing = "other texxt"
    let thirdThing = "multiple lines! look ma! look at this!"

    let cellData = [firstThing, secondThing, thirdThing]
    let text = cellData[indexPath.row]

    cell.cellText.text = text


    //configure muh buttons
    cell.yes.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "yes_unselected"), for: .normal)
    cell.yes.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "yes_selected"), for: .selected)
    cell.no.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "no_unselected"), for: .normal)
    cell.no.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "no_selected"), for: .selected)
    cell.na.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "na_unselected"), for: .normal)
    cell.na.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "na_selected"), for: .selected)

    cell.delegate = self


    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

//delegate code

func filledOut(controller: DepressedSelectionTableViewCell, selections: Int!, isClicked: Bool!) {
    choices.append(selections)
    if isClicked == true {

        advanceArray.append(1)
    }
    if advanceArray.count == 3 {
        print(choices.reduce(0, +))
        result = (choices.reduce(0, +))
        print(advanceArray.count)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("TableViewToDepressedParent"), object: nil)
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please edit your question to include relevant code

Comment: Thank you. I have included the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right general idea. A table view is a view object that displays information about a model object and gathers input from the user. You want to save that input back into the model.

For non-sectioned table views an array of structs is often all you need as a data model. You can pass that array around to any view controller that needs to display information from the model. You can use that approach for master-detail, where the user taps on a cell to go to details about that item (simply pass the index of the selected cell to the detail view controller.)

In your case you want to display all the contents of your array in 2 places, so you would save the button states into the entries in your array, and then display those states in both view controllers.

If it's not working you'll need to edit your post to show your code. Show the data model. Show how it's being passed between view controllers. Show how you're installing info from your model into your table views (by posting your table view dataSource methods - particularly `cellForRow(at:)`.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I've added the relevant code. I feel like I'm close to understanding what you're saying, but I don't know where I would create that array. Would it just be an array of variables modified when the user clicks a button in a given cell?